# Why it shows error: expected expression before ‘return’?

Tags: c++, c, embedded

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
int x=1,y=0;
x>y?printf("Hello World"):return x;
}
```

Why it shows error: expected expression before ‘return’?
What is the thing need to be changed here?

Comment: May I ask what is the purpose of writing this, instead of an `if`?

Comment: This is improper use of a ternary (`? :`). Ternaries expect expressions: things that themselves evaluate to a value. `return` doesn't evaluate to anything though; it's a control statement. If you want to conditionally **do** something (instead of conditionally picking a value), use a full `if`. Even if what you're trying to do worked, it would be poor form.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is ill formed, im not seeing anything [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other) that says you can return from one of the branches of the ternary.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and avoid ternary operators.  Modern compilers are good at optimizing `if-else` statements, so there is little use for the ternary operators.  In modern embedded systems, focus on readability and quality and less on efficiency and space concerns.  If your program doesn't fit, then optimize for space (with the compiler's help).  If your program is running too slow or missing timing opportunities, then optimize for speed, again, with the compiler's help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why it shows error: expected expression before ‘return’?

The ternary operator is an *operator*, requiring three operands.  The first operand must be an expression of integer type.  The latter two operands must be expressions of type compatible with each other.

A `return` statement specifies a return value for the function in which it appears, and causes that function to terminate.  It is not an expression, and does not evaluate to a value, neither the specified return value or any other.  As such, **it cannot be an operand of the ternary operator**.

The error message is, therefore, expressing that the third operand of the ternary operator is missing, which it is, since the `return` statement cannot be considered an operand.  If it were present, that operand would appear before the `return`.

> What is the thing need to be changed here?

To obtain the logic you appear to want, the thing to change is the ternary operator.  Use an `if` / `else` statement instead:

```
if (x > y) {
    printf("Hello World");
} else {
    return x;
}
```

Generally speaking, the ternary operator should be avoided.  It usually makes code harder to read and understand, with little or no offsetting benefit.  You may someday discover a programming context where a ternary is the cleanest, clearest way to go, but anywhere else, use `if`.

Answer (score 0):

The main theme of the ternary operator is

`condition ? value_if_true : value_if_false`

The statement evaluates to `value_if_true` if the condition is met, and `value_if_false` otherwise.

Read more about 'ternary operator' [https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/c-ternary-operator/]

Try to avoid a ternary operator if your concept is not clear. Try to use `if-else`.